# Determine a set recursively given the basis and recursive steps

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> A set $S$ is defined recursively by:
>
> - Basis step: $0\in S$
> - Recursive step: if $a\in S$ then $a+3\in S$ and $a+5\in S$
>
> Determine the set $S\cap\{a\in Z\;|\;0<a<12\}$

My thinking is since $a$ is $0$ member of $a$. Since $a>0$ my first term is assuming $a=1$ then $a + 3 = 4$, $a+5 =6$ so the next term is $a+7 =8$ then $a+9 =10$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You can learn how to type mathematical formulas in a beautiful way [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine a set recursively](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186047/determine-a-set-recursively)

Comment: You asked this question [a few days ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2186047/401264). You need to just edit that one with your work and flag it for reopening

Comment: its not flagging

Comment: lioness99a can you help???

Comment: Try [these answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1324845/401264) to exactly the same question as yours

Comment: Assuming $a=1$ is unjustified. Given the rules, from $a=0$ you deduce $a=3$ and $a+5$ are in $S$.